# 異なる文字数の、文字列類似度の算出方法は？

Tags: アルゴリズム

**下記が50％だとすると、**

> 天下
>    天一

---

**下記は類似度何％になるでしょうか？**
・一致数4 ÷ 全文字数22 × 100 ＝ 22％でしょうか？
・また、この場合、「天下」から見た「天下一武道会へ出場してみたいけど」も、「天下一武道会へ出場してみたいけど」から見た「天下」の類似度も同じ？

> 天下
>    天下一武道会へ出場してみたいけど

---

その他、どんな「算出方法」や「考え方」があるか知りたいです

Comment: 比率で表したものではないですが、たとえば[レーベンシュタイン距離](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%99%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E8%B7%9D%E9%9B%A2)ですとか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

クラスタリングを利用するという手もあります。
この場合、学習データにより、類似度が異なることになります。
http://qiita.com/shima_x/items/196e8d823412e45680e9

なんらかのジャンルにより異なった結果が欲しい場合は、こちらが適しているかと思いますが、単純にどの程度編集すると、その文字列になるのかという解が欲しいのであれば、すでに提示されている方法が適していると思います。

Answer (score 2):

定番といえるようなアルゴリズムがあるのかどうか、私が検索した限りでは見つけられませんでした。「レーベンシュタイン距離」を用いるなら、想定される最大コストをmc,レーベンシュタイン距離をldとして、

**類似度(%) = (mc-ld)/mc * 100**

とすると、
**'天下':'天一'->50%

'天下':'天下一武道会へ出場してみたいけど'->12%

'天下一武道会へ出場してみたいけど':'天下'->12%

'天下':'武道会へ出場してみたいけど'->0%

'天一':'天下一武道会へ出場してみたいけど'->12%**
なんて結果になります。

レーベンシュタイン距離の計算はネットで見つけたJavaScript版のIterative with full matrix相当のもの、「想定される最大のコスト」は`mc = Math.max(str1.length, str2.length)`で計算しています。(どちらもサロゲートペアの文字は考慮されていません。)

どなたかが、定番のアルゴリズムを見つけてこられた場合、単なるお茶濁しとなりますが、参考まで。